# How to remove data in Robot Framework using regular expression pattern

Tags: robotframework

I'm want to extract few data without passing it directly like this,

```
    ${log_line}    Set Variable    {name:abc}[abc@xyz:(pg)]
    ${cleaned_log}    Remove string    ${log_line}    [abc@xyz:(pg)]
    Log ${cleaned_log}
```

Instead, trying below code with regular expression pattern. But it is not working as expected. Is there any other way? Inputs from anyone would be very helpful..
expected output- {name:abc}

```
    ${log_line}    Set Variable    {name:abc}[abc@xyz:(pq)]
    ${cleaned_log}    Replace string    ${log_line}    \[.*?\]    ${EMPTY}
    Log ${cleaned_log}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword [Replace String Using Regexp](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String%20Using%20Regexp) can be used instead

```
*** Test Cases ***
Replace using Regexp
    ${log_line}        Set Variable    {name:abc}[abc@xyz:(pg)]
    ${cleaned_log}     Remove String Using Regexp    ${log_line}    \\[.*?\]    ${EMPTY}
    Log                ${cleaned_log}
```

More information regarding the use of regular expression can be found here: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Match%20Regexp. Hope this helps.